# Does the prime minister die at the end?

Tags: code-breaker

The [Code Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code%3aBreaker) anime has an open ended finish (so I'm thinking a sequel?!) but it's not clear to me if the prime minister dies at the end or not. Hitomi used his abilities on him and at the end the prime minister spits blood but it's not clear if he also dies.

Does the manga mention this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anime and manga have quite different storylines. Therefore, whether the prime minister dies in the anime or not is up for debate, but in the manga chapter 227, it explicitly shows the prime minister burning to ashes after overusing the seven flames, as well as a news broadcast in chapter 228 about the death of the prime minister, with the next panel having normal citizens commenting on how his death will affect politics.
It is up to you to use the events of the manga to make sure whether the prime minister dies at the end of the anime. In my opinion, though, I think it's best to keep the events of the anime and manga separate.
One thing to note about my answer: I haven't watched the anime fully yet. I will check the last episode, however, and update this answer accordingly.

Edit: Just saw the ending of the anime. The story of the anime is so different from that of the manga that I think whether the prime minister dies in the anime or not will always just be speculation.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew the anime and the manga had different story lines. Guess we'll have to wait for the sequel to see what happens...

Comment: If there will indeed be a sequel to the anime.
I hope there is, but I somewhat doubt it.